Access team meeting chat before the meeting starts when created using API
I am creating an event using Event API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and creating a teams meeting using online meeting API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#onlinemeetin.... But the participants are unable to start the chat in teams before the meeting is started. Participants can start the chat if I manually create a meeting from the team's calendar. Please guide me on how I can enable the participants to start the chat before the meeting is started. I have the following flags set when create the online meeting -
allowMeetingChat: "enabled",
shareMeetingChatHistoryDefault: "all",
allowedPresenters: "everyone",

Participants are seeing this error -

